# System.Threading.Task Is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

System.Threading.Tasks is not Working in my project. 
I has been trying to use All DLL   regarded This  error
I Search various Code
But Did not Get Any Solution

I am Using Asp.net 2008 (3.5)

Error show here -

> The type or namespace name 'Tasks' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

so help me
thanks

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? And what do you mean by "everything is null reference"? (It sounds like you've got a compile-time error, rather than an execution time exception...)

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5 Version.It is Compile-time error

Answer (score 16):

This library is not available in .NET 3.5, make sure that you are targeting .NET 4.0 in your project properties.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The correct class (and namespace) name is [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) which is located in `mscorlib.dll` and is available in `.NET 4`+. If you want to use it in `.NET 3.5`, you can do this by using [Microsoft Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896).

Answer (score 4):

**Finding a Package**
From the **Tools** menu, select **Library Package Manager** and then click **Package Manager Console**

[image]

The **Package Manager Console** window is displayed.

[image]

Write **Install-Package System.Threading.dll** in console and press ENTER

```
PM> Install-Package System.Threading.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missing typing.

The right class name is [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) not `Tasks` and it belongs on [`System.Threading.Tasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Which Dll use To This Erorr

Answer (score 0):

Turn on 'Enable Just My Code' in Visual Studio | Tools | Debugging | General.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem in one of my legacy projects, I had to add System.Threading.Tasks assembly to .Net 3.5 and then include it in the project. To do that, I first had to download a NuGet package from the official https://www.nuget.org/downloads site. Windows x86 command line option https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe was the one I picked. All it did, was download the respective nuget.exe which I placed into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools" folder designated for VS 2008 tools. Having prepared that, I followed Scott Hanselman's instructions here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/nuget-support-for-visual-studio-2008 to configure a new External Tool named "NuGet Install". Even if you skip the last few steps of creating a toolbar and adding a button to it, you will still have this new option "NuGet Install" under the Tools-menu. Just make sure to prepend the command line nuget.exe (as the web-site suggests) with a complete path to the folder where you placed the downloaded file. That is it, at least as far as the setup steps go. Now you can just select that option and substitute the words "your.package.name" with "System.Threading.dll", which instructs the Visual Studio to add this assembly to your project as a package. Once done so, add a new reference by navigating to and selecting the System.Threading.dll (under Packages-folder in your solution), then simply add "include System.Threading.Tasks;" line to the class that needs to use it.